# Map is showing blank after coming back from another app?

Tags: flutter, dictionary, dart

Here is my code. I think this is happening because of animate camera. But I already define the animateCamera.[screenshot, When app is running](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0iQzI.jpg) after this, when I open some other app and then came back to the app. The map is blank.

```
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _location = Location();
    setCurrentLocation();
    _add();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    super.dispose();
  }

  setCurrentLocation() async {
    currentLocation = await _location.getLocation();
    setState(() {
      cLat = currentLocation.latitude;
      cLong = currentLocation.longitude;
    });
  }

  Future<Uint8List> getBytesFromAsset(String path, int width) async {
    ByteData data = await rootBundle.load(path);
    ui.Codec codec = await ui.instantiateImageCodec(data.buffer.asUint8List(),
        targetWidth: width);
    ui.FrameInfo fi = await codec.getNextFrame();
    return (await fi.image.toByteData(format: ui.ImageByteFormat.png))
        .buffer
        .asUint8List();
  }

  void _add() {
    widget.porters.forEach((porter) async {
      final Uint8List tractorIcon =
          await getBytesFromAsset('assets/images/cariePorter.png', 120);

      if (porter.latitude != null && porter.longitude != null) {
        final String markerIdVal = 'marker_id_$_markerIdCounter';
        _markerIdCounter++;
        final MarkerId markerId = MarkerId(markerIdVal);

        final Marker marker = Marker(
          icon: BitmapDescriptor.fromBytes(tractorIcon),
          markerId: markerId,
          position: LatLng(
            porter.latitude,
            porter.longitude,
          ),
        );

        markers[markerId] = marker;
        setState(() {
          // ignore: unnecessary_statements
          markers;
        });
      }
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return (currentLocation != null)
        ? Container(
            height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
            child: new GoogleMap(
              mapToolbarEnabled: false,
              gestureRecognizers: <Factory<OneSequenceGestureRecognizer>>[
                new Factory<OneSequenceGestureRecognizer>(
                  () => new EagerGestureRecognizer(),
                ),
              ].toSet(),
              markers: Set<Marker>.of(markers.values),
              mapType: MapType.normal,
              compassEnabled: false,
              myLocationEnabled: true,
              myLocationButtonEnabled: true,
              initialCameraPosition: _kGooglePlex,
              zoomControlsEnabled: false,
              onCameraMove: (CameraPosition position) {},
              onMapCreated: _onMapCreated,
            ),
          )
        : Container(
            height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.8,
            child: Center(
                child: Column(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children: <Widget>[
                LoadingWidget2(
                  size: 100,
                ),
                Text('Loading....'),
              ],
            )));
  }

  void _onMapCreated(GoogleMapController controller) {
    controller.setMapStyle(MapElementsColor.mapStyles);
    _controller.complete(controller);
    controller.animateCamera(CameraUpdate.newCameraPosition(
      CameraPosition(
        bearing: 270.0,
        target: LatLng(cLat, cLong),
        tilt: 30.0,
        zoom: 18.0000,
      ),
    ));
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be caused by losing the state of the app when leaving and returning to the app.

The state of the page that you are looking for in this case, would be onResumed add the following code in your page which will reinitialize the map when the user returns back to the app

```
@override
void didChangeAppLifecycleState(AppLifecycleState state) {
  if(state == AppLifecycleState.resumed){
    _location = Location();
    setCurrentLocation();
    _add();
  }
}
```

Comment: Did not work, I think setCurrentLocation() will set the location, it's fine, but map lose the state, how can I revive map, when I came back to the app.